# How to add win7 and win10 boot item into debian's boot menu?

Tags: debian, boot, windows

At first only one disk `wdc` on my pc,`win7 and debian9` installed on it,and `win7` is in `debian9`'s boot menu.
Today i buy and set a new hard disk (`st`),installed `win10` on it, then installed `debian10` on it again.
[image]

According to the image, `wdc` is abbreviation of `WD2500AAKX-OOERMAO`,`st` reference to `ST1000VX000`.
Reboot and enter into bios,if i choose `wdc` to boot,i find that `win10` lost.
[image]
I can only choose the bottom line `press F9 to use a different operating system`,entered `win7`,no `win10`.
If i choose `wdc` to boot,both `debian10` and `debian9` can boot,no `win7` and `win10` in boot menu.
How can i write `win7` and `win10` into the boot menu which contains `debian9` and `debian10`?
[image]

```
df |grep  sd
/dev/sdb5      145346580 99315556  38578148  73% /
/dev/sda5      191196044  6947112 174466968   4% /media/debian9/5d5180e5-0401-42b1-a60e-4f006613dd79
/dev/sda1      204799996 60649924 144150072  30% /media/debian9/903EA3B53EA39330
/dev/sda7      551166744    73756 523025508   1% /media/debian9/8a80d376-1a85-4b66-b593-f5f18e1abf1f
/dev/sdb2       59775996 57593612   2182384  97% /media/debian9/D8A2B792A2B7741A
/dev/sdb3       30716924 25743424   4973500  84% /media/debian9/New Volume
```

`win7` installed on `/dev/sdb2`,`debian9` installed on `/dev/sdb5`,`win10` installed on `/dev/sda1`,`debian10` installed on `/dev/sda5`. 
Do as KGELYU say,`win10` show in boot menu!

[image]
I select the third item to boot `win10`,strange thing happen!

[image]

Now, i have three choices,press `enter` and press `F8` take no effect,so i press `f9`,`win7` come back instead of `win10`!!!
How to fix it?

I reinstall both win10 and debian10 for several times.at last ,success!The most important thing is that to set `secure bios` as `other os` when to install debian10(install win10 first then debian10).
But there is still issue remains :`win7` lost !
`sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` can write `win0` ,instead of `win7` in boot menu.

Comment: Are both versions of Windows UEFI or both BIOS, and is Debian in same boot mode. You cannot change boot mode, once you start to boot. Windows typically installs the boot files from a second install into the boot partition of the first install. So does Windows 7 BCD now have Windows 10 files & Windows 7 added to BCD. You can do a work around and add Windows boot files to other install if BIOS or create another ESP and let Windows 10 install UEFI boot files to it and change ESP back. Grub will find files as it searches for files not flags. And often better to have ESP on each drive if UEFI.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```